# Firebase: Suddenly can't deploy anymore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I never had any problems deploying with my project. Suddenly I can't, and I have no idea why. I am getting this error:

```
Error: HTTP Error: 400, Location must equal europe-west1 because the App Engine app that is associated with this project is located in europe-west1
```

But I don't know whose location it's referring to. All my functions are in `europe-west1` as you can see from the console log:

```
+  firestore: released rules firestore.rules to cloud.firestore
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function generateThumbs(europe-west1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function handleFinishedAuctions(europe-west1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function stripeCharge(europe-west1)...
i  scheduler: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  pubsub: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  scheduler: all necessary APIs are enabled
+  pubsub: all necessary APIs are enabled
```

Also, my Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resource location is `eur3 (europe-west)`.

Why is this happening? What can I do to fix it? Thanks.